# Access HubCallContext outside the SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, signalr

i want to get query string outside the hub which is a property of HubCallerContext

I can get a query string on the hub like this

```
Context.QueryString["Key"]
```

Comment: In .NET Core, you would inject an `IHubContext<SomeHub>` into your class. In .NET Framework, I believe it is something like `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SomeHub>`.

Comment: GetHubContext don't have QueryString property

Comment: let me try i will let you know

Comment: i get null when try to cast into HubCallerContext

Comment: What's type when you debug then? How do you use your utility class anyway? You may be able to pass it the query string of a specific connection.

Comment: type is Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubContext , yeah i can pass it but this will required too much change

Comment: The thing is that the `GlobalHost` doesn't keep track of query parameters for the individual calls. You need to capture these in the hub yourself.